# Trying to view Post Infos on graph.facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<postid>
```

to view infos about a post placed on the Facebook wall by some users.

(postid = userid_postid, e.g. 25255265222_12622622626 so dont worry about the format).

I recieve following, but I´m sure the Post exists:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request.",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
  }
}
```

Why do I get the Error message? Whats wrong?

thx 4 help
Neil

Answer (score 0):

You can't access Users' posts without using an active `access_token`

Try:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{User_ID}_{POST_ID}?access_token={Active Access Toke}
```

Or (Works as well):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{POST_ID}?access_token={Active Access Toke}
```

PS: Did you use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=25255265222_12622622626)?

Comment: ok, then its impossible, cause I only use FB.ui to share our Infos, so no access token gets responded. And we also wanna access the post weeks and month later to controll if the user didnt delete it. So we just will use:    https://www.facebook.com/userid/posts/postid  to check that.